# Receiving errors in my form control with Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Receiving multiple errors due to my form control in Angular:
[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let formOne of uiListElement">
        <h2>
            {{formOne.$.name}}
        </h2>
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <div class="col-lg-4" *ngFor="let form of formOne.UIElement">
                <div class="form-group" [ngSwitch]="form.$.type">
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="'string'">
                        <label _ngcontent-emf-c46="" for="input1">{{form.$.name}}</label>
                        <input _ngcontent-emf-c46="" type="text"  placeholder="" id="input1"
                            aria-describedby="Text field" name="name" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"
                            ng-reflect-name="name" ng-reflect-model="">
                        <div *ngIf="xmlForm.get(form.$.name).dirty || xmlForm.get(form.$.name).touched">
                            <small class="error" *ngIf="xmlForm.get(form.$.name).errors?.required">
                                {{form.$.name}} is Required
                            </small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="'number'">
                        <label _ngcontent-emf-c46="" for="input1">{{form.$.name}}</label>
                        <input _ngcontent-emf-c46="" type="text"  placeholder="" id="input1"
                            aria-describedby="Text field" name="name" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"
                            ng-reflect-name="name" ng-reflect-model="">
                        <div *ngIf="xmlForm.get(form.$.name).dirty || xmlForm.get(form.$.name).touched">
                            <small class="error" *ngIf="!xmlForm.get(form.$.name).errors?.required">
                                {{form.$.name}} is Required
                            </small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here is my form control method:

```
createFormControl() {

    this.uiListElement.forEach((element: UIListElement) => {
      if (element.UIElement.$.required === "true"){
        this.xmlForm.addControl(element.UIElement.$.name, new FormControl('', [Validators.required]));
      }
      else{
        this.xmlForm.addControl(element.UIElement.$.name, new FormControl(''));
      }
    })
  }
```

I am not sure why I am running into these errors, help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error `Cannot read property "<some property>" of null/undefined` means that the object, that your are trying to get `<some property>` of, is a null/undefined - it either dosent exist, if `undefined`, or is a value of `null`. Now in your case you cant get a property `dirty`. doing ctrl+f for `.dirty` finds `xmlForm.get(form.$.name).dirty`,. to make sure its not a null, i would recomend printing it out to console to check if it contains a value. Most likely it dosent. Comment out the areas where `.dirty` is used and then try to figure out why `xmlForm.get(form.$.name)` is null.

Comment: @Lith I'm thinking it is undefined/null because it has something to do with my two `ngFor` loops and my `createFormControl` method. If I comment out all of the form control in the HTML, the html builds and the properties have values.